# Extend LVM size

Tags: linux, ubuntu, lvm, resize2fs

I have an EC2 instance which has 2 EBS (1 x 200G, 1 x 100G).

Below is the output of `lsblk`

```
NAME                MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
xvde1               202:65   0  200G  0 disk /
xvdj                202:144  0  100G  0 disk 
└─xvdj1             202:145  0  100G  0 part 
  └─data-www (dm-0) 253:0    0   50G  0 lvm  /var/www
```

So my understanding by reading this is 2 disks, xvdj has a partition called xvdj1 which uses the full capacity of the disk of xvdj.
My end goal is to set the LVM data-www to use the full capacity of xvdj1.

`pvdisplay` Output

```
  --- Physical volume ---
  PV Name               /dev/xvdj1
  VG Name               data
  PV Size               50.00 GiB / not usable 2.97 MiB
  Allocatable           yes (but full)
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              12799
  Free PE               0
  Allocated PE          12799
  PV UUID               pIA4pl-HON1-ZKTu-cLZP-b0Xf-c0rc-AeFdvG
```

`df -h` output

```
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/xvde1            197G   12G  176G   7% /
tmpfs                 1.7G     0  1.7G   0% /dev/shm
/dev/mapper/data-www   50G   40G  9.5G  81% /var/www
```

`lvdisplay` output

```
 --- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/data/www
  LV Name                www
  VG Name                data
  LV UUID                VUqXne-IX7g-H5wV-DNGd-32ZV-kYzX-XnBybh
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time topaz.zyber.co.nz, 2014-03-14 10:37:49 +1300
  LV Status              available
  # open                 1
  LV Size                50.00 GiB
  Current LE             12799
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     256
  Block device           253:0
```

I am simply lost on what needs to be done.
the LVM that needs extending, already has data. Best case scenario would be to extend it without data loss.

Answer (score 2):

Your LVM physical volume is 50GB, yet the partition it's in is 100GB. To use most of the capacity for the `www` logical volume you need to perform three steps:

1. Enlarge the LVM physical volume: `pvresize /dev/xvdj1`
2. Enlarge your `www` logical volume: `lvextend -l 100%FREE /dev/data/www`
3. Enlarge your filesystem, which depends on which filesystem you are using.

Note: You may be able to use the `-r` option with `lvextend` to resize the logical volume and filesystem with a single command.

Comment: Hi, thanks. What command would I use for point 3? /dev/mapper/data-www is shown as ext3 when I do df -Th. Thanks

Comment: Also just wondering if this method would cause any data loss. Sorry for all the newbie questions

Comment: Well, you SHOULD not loose any data because the filesystem size is being increased. BUT, it's always best to take precaution when manipulating filesystems and have a plan that's ready to go in case the filesystem becomes corrupted. That said, for ext3 you can use `resize2fs /dev/data/www`. There are cases when you can increase the size of an ext3 filesystem while it is still mounted. You can read the `resize2fs` for the details. Or, simply unmount the filesystem prior to resizing.