# Oracle VM Vitualbox - Extend centos root file system

Tags: linux, centos, filesystems, virtualbox, lvm

I first installed the centos on the virtual box and only assigned 8GB to it. Now I've extended the VIRTUAL BOX file system and it has around 25gb.

As you can see below it's showing as tmpfs when I do "df -h" command and when I do "lsblk" it's showing root file system has 20gb. How can I extend the centos-root file system?

And, what is tmpfs?

[image: information of file systems]

Comment: (1) Please post text (e.g., command-line commands and output) *as text* and not as images (screenshots). (2) The `tmpfs` lines have nothing to do with your question. (3) Please do a web search for “tmpfs”.  You will find lots of information.  If you have problems understanding what you find, *then* ask a question here. (4) The `lsblk` output shows that your virtual disk is 25 GB, and the root filesystem is 8 GB.  I don’t see 20 GB anywhere.

Comment: See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/468252/extend-lvm-size/468255#468255

Comment: partition sda2 is 9G, you should create  a sda3 with the rest, and add it as physical disk (in LVM way).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to create a new partition and extend your lvm `/dev/mapper/centos-root`.

Firstly, let's create `/dev/sda3`:

```
$ echo "n\np\n\n\n\nw" | fdisk /dev/sda
```

(you can manually give the values if you prefer with `fdisk /dev/sda` - the above just uses defaults - i.e. all the space on the next partition number available)

Now, we need to create it as a physical volume:

```
$ pvcreate /dev/sda3
```

Once, that's done, we have to extend the volume group first, then the LVM.

To find the volume group:

```
$ vgs
  VG       #PV #LV #SN Attr   VSize  VFree
  VolGroup   1   2   0 wz--n- 19.51g    0
```

So the volume group’s name in this example is “VolGroup” Let’s extend it:

```
$ vgextend VolGroup /dev/sda3
```

Running `vgs` should now show the new size.

Now for the LVM extension. find the true path with `lvdisplay`:

```
$ lvdisplay | grep Path
  LV Path                /dev/VolGroup/lv_root
```

Then extend it:

```
$ lvextend /dev/VolGroup/lv_root /dev/sda3
```

Now, `lvdisplay` or `lvs` will show the new size. But the filesystem still isn't extended if you check in `df -h` - we need to resize that.

There are a few ways of doing this live (whilst the server is running and not in recovery), the one you use will depend on the file system type.

You can easily find the fs type with `mount | grep mapper`.

For `ext3/4`, use `resize2fs`:

```
$ resize2fs /dev/mapper/VolGroup-lv_root
```

Note that I'm using `/dev/mapper/VolGroup-lv_root` - as in the filepath in the output of `df -h`.

for `xfs` use `xfs_growfs`:

```
$ xfs_growfs /dev/mapper/VolGroup-lv_root
```

Then `df -h` should show the new size.